# Networkx Adjacency Matrix Condition

Tags: python, networkx

I am working with a directed graph containing 33 nodes and have a distance matrix containing the distances between each pair of nodes. I now want to create a "coverage 0-1-matrix", that has an entry 1 if node i can cover node j and 0 otherwise. A node can be covered by another node if the shortest path between those nodes is shorter than 5000. How can I create such a matrix?

I have removed all edges that are > 5000 from my graph, but now I do not know how to achieve the 0-1-matrix result.

Comment: In case your distance matrix `D` is a numpy array, you can simply do `A = np.array(A <= r, dtype=np.int32)`. Then, `A[i,j]` is 1 if `D[i,j] <= r` and `0` otherwise.

Comment: [This]( https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length) is what you're looking for, right?

Comment: Joni's Solution worked perfectly, thank you so much to both of you!